# PDFKIT formatting header/footers

Tags: css, pdfkit

I am setting the PDFKIT headers/footers via the options. Everything is outputting fine.

```
options = {
    'page-size'    : 'Letter',
    'margin-top'   : '0.75in',
    'margin-right' : '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.5in',
    'margin-left'  : '0.75in',
    'header-left'  : 'something',
    'header-right' : '[section]',
    'footer-right' : '[page]',
}
```

But how do I format them via css code?

I was thinking this would work but it does not.

```
@page {
  @top-left {
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: red;
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered that the size, font, etc... are just more options. Oops.

```
  --header-center <text>          Centered header text
  --header-font-name <name>       Set header font name (default Arial)
  --header-font-size <size>       Set header font size (default 12)
  --header-html <url>             Adds a html header
  --header-left <text>            Left aligned header text
  --header-line                   Display line below the header
  --no-header-line                Do not display line below the header
  --header-right <text>           Right aligned header text
  --header-spacing <real>         Spacing between header and content in mm
```